# How to enable selective app permissions on CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, permissions

One of the big reasons I installed CyanogenMod (10.1 latest Monthly) was to be able to have the ability to selectively deny apps certain permissions (most importantly the network and device ID ones). However, I am not able to find it in the settings, in spite of there being blog and forum posts from several months ago mentioning that CM will have this feature.

Does anyone know if this ever made it to the main ROM? If I want to include it myself, is there a specific source tree I can merge into the CM main repo code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was available in CM7, but got removed in CM9 and above, for reasons I do not know myself.

It is possible that the maintainers of CM couldn't find a way to make this compatible with Android 4+ and so left it out.

There are apps on the market that can do this, such as [Permissions Denied](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stericson.permissions.donate) however this is now a paid app, and I am unable to report whether this works.

EDIT: Ad eldarerathis pointed out in the comments, [there is an open feature request](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-28) to add this to CM10 and later. I suggest you follow this request for updates.

Comment: Thanks for this folks! As per [this comment on the issue](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=6008#c23), _"On the title of this Enhancement/Feature request: The ability to revoke per app permissions is an active request and something are considering bringing back/implementing. End of this particular request's status. "_ :)

Comment: There's also [LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite) as a free app for up to ICS. Be aware however that the playstore version has issues with Jelly Bean (head to XDA for solutions).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer as such, more of a work-around.

The other poster mentioned paid apps that can revoke permissions. I suggest to try using [SRT AppGuard](http://www.srt-appguard.com/), I've used it to install apps that aren't supposed to be on a tablet on my Nexus 7 and other wifi-only devices (most notably WhatsApp) by revoking the device ID permission.